# Why is the maximum recursion depth in python 1000?

Tags: python

I was curious about what the MRD (maximum recursion depth) is in python, so i wrote this:

```
def call(n):
    print (n)
    return call(n+1)

call(1)
```

The end result was 979, wich is a peculiar number for me. I could not find anywhere why this number is the standard. As i am a self taught programmer i would apreciate it being explained in simple terms.

EDIT: apperantly it's supposed to be a 1000, but why this number?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/maximum-recursion-depth - Read this, it gives you the answer you want..

Comment: He ask why its there, and i am asking why it is like that. I want to know why my result was 979, **not** why there is a MRD or how to get around it.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit)?

Comment: I also tried it in the shell now, still stop at 979 for me. Docs does not give any information on the standard recursion limit.

Comment: Because there isn't a real "standard recursion limit" - it can be set by the implementation (and for CPython, which most people refer to as just Python, it is set to 1000 by default). Also it can be changed (which was originally part of your question) as the documentation describes

Comment: Why is the default 1000? why not 1'000'000, why not 10 or 1024?

Comment: Because the programmers that implemented CPython decided (probably based on their expertise and experience) that it is a good default value that will be sufficient for most programs written in Python

Comment: Why is 1000 a good default value that will be sufficient for most programs written in Python?

Comment: Which part of "the programmers that implemented CPython decided (probably based on their expertise and experience)" was unclear to you? If you really want to know ask them. I neither wrote CPython nor decided the default value.

Comment: `RuntimeError: maximum "why question" depth exceeded`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a better test:

```
n = 0

def test_recursion_limit():
    def call():
        global n
        n += 1
        call()
    try:
        call()
    except RuntimeError:
        print(n)

test_recursion_limit()
```

If you put it in `spam.py` and execute that, it should return 998 for both python2 and python3.  It's one stack frame short because of the initial `test_recursion_limit` frame.

If you're running in a REPL such as ipython, you are already inside a few frames, so you will see a lower count - it's not that the recursion limit is undershot, it's that the implementation of the REPL itself uses some stack frames.

```
>>> # freshly opened ipython session
>>> import inspect
>>> len(inspect.stack())
10
```

You can check the current recursion limit by calling `sys.getrecursionlimit()` function.  The default value of 1000 is chosen as a sensible default, it's a safeguard against eclipsing system resources when you accidentally execute an infinitely recursive call.  That's very easy to do when mucking around with custom `__getattr__` implementations, for example.

If you're blowing the stack legitimately and you need to increase the limit, it can be modified with `sys.setrecursionlimit`.

Comment: I did as you instructed and it returned 994

Comment: So that explains why its not 1000, but _why is recursion the limit 1000?_

Comment: Why not?  How often do you need to recurse deeper than 1000?  I've used python for about a decade and have never needed to reconfigure `sys.setrecursionlimit` even once.  Every time I hit the recursion limit it was my own fault or a bug.

Comment: So 1000 is more than enough?

Comment: Yeah, for most use-cases, 1000 is plenty.